# Repeating Chrome extension error "failed to redirect"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, redirection, wikipedia, https-everywhere

Occasionally, when opening a wikipedia page I get this type of error in Chrome:

> Warning: This extension failed to redirect a network request to
>   http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lymphoma because another extension (HTTPS
>   Everywhere) redirected it to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lymphoma.

While it seems that it doesn't affect anything significant, it keeps causing me to click the 3-bars button and check the error, which is just annoying.

Any idea how to get rid of this without having to disable my extensions?

Comment: Your Wikiwand and HTTPS Everywhere extensions are conflicting. Either disable one of them, or try excluding Wikipedia from the latter.

Comment: What part of "rid of this without having to disable my extensions" wasn't clear? :p

Comment: Do the latter then. It's one or the other. If you want to do neither then live with the annoyance, simple.

Comment: I couldn't find any way to disable domains... do you know how to do it?

Comment: Create an exclusion ruleset. [This](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets) should help.

Comment: Now Wikipedia is HSTS, disabling HTTPS Everywhere won't help anything.

Answer (score 3):

#### General problem

two (Chrome/Web)-Extensions tried to redirect the same request. [In this case](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#implementation)

> the most recently installed extension wins and all others are ignored.

[uBlock](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/1170) (and others) consider this **non-fixable** on their part, as

> An extension is not notified if its instruction to modify or redirect has been ignored.

#### Your problem

[As mentioned](https://superuser.com/questions/925524/repeating-chrome-extension-error-failed-to-redirect#comment1252721_925524), it seems that you can [exclude specific patterns from HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets), as in

```
<exclusion pattern="^http://(?:\w+\.)?stack(?:exchange|overflow)\.com/users/authenticate/" />
```

It should be possible to exclude all wikipedia.org links, as the wikiwand extension then redirects to wikiwand.com (if that works), but [wikiwand acknowledges](https://wikiwand.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/413411-i-installed-the-extension-but-it-still-doesn-t-red):

> There are some known problems with those extensions: Kill Evil, HTTPS Everywhere

... but not on [the main conflicts list](https://wikiwand.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/528907-which-extensions-conflict-with-wikiwand).

It seems as if [wikipedia already uses `https`](https://superuser.com/questions/925524/repeating-chrome-extension-error-failed-to-redirect#comment1287402_925524), so simply excluding wikipedia.org would not pose a problem.